# Extracting text from a hidden image

Tags: cryptography

Say i have cropped an image and have hidden some part of it, like shown below

[image]

Is it possible for anyone to download this image and able to decipher what the hidden text is?

Comment: I think the question is too general; the answer will depend on how you have hidden/obscured part of the text.  What research have you done?  There's lots written on revealing redacted text.  I encourage you to do some research on that question, then edit your question to summarize what you've been able to find (make it interesting and useful for readers) and make the question more focused.

Comment: Okay D.W. Will surely work on your suggestions, and edit the question. Thank you.